# What does "sniffed" mean in this context?

Tags: harry-potter, language-explanation

> “May I take you through to the dining room, Mrs. Mason?” said Dudley, offering his fat arm to an invisible woman. “My perfect little gentleman!” sniffed Aunt Petunia. “And you?” said Uncle Vernon viciously to Harry. “I’ll be in my room, making no noise and pretending I’m not there,” said Harry dully.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* (1998)</sub>

I would think she is saying "My perfect little gentleman" delightfully, but 'sniffed' often expresses contempt or dissatisfaction. So what does it mean?

Answer (score 10):

People also sniff when they get a bit teary, as tearing up also makes your nose runny, and one (stereotypical) reason for a mother to tear up is motherly pride.

This is being used in the passage to show that Petunia is getting a little emotional at her smart little cherub's performance.

Comment: This is supported by the surrounding context as well. For example, *"They'll* love *him!" cried Aunt Petunia rapturously.* And *This was too much for both Aunt Petunia and Harry. Aunt Petunia burst into tears and hugged her son, while Harry ducked under the table so they wouldn't see him laughing.*